# Doctrine query builder find by interests

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

today i have an interest task - realize search on DB by some groups and sort it by most relevant criteria

1. We have 2 entities (User and Interests) on Symfony with ManyToMany relation
2. We need create query for find users which have most similar interests
   ex:

   user1 have interests [1,2,3,4,5]

   user2 have interests [1,2,4,5,7]

   user3 have interests [3,5]

we try find user with interests [2,6,7] and result must be:

```
[user2, user1, user0]

user2 - 2 similar interests

user1 - 1 similar interests

user3 - 0
```

Code example:

```
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Many Users have Many Interests.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Interest")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_interests",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="interest_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $interests;
...
```

I have no idea how to organize it nicely, can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure User <-> Interests is not a ManyToMany relation?

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: yep, sorry, i miss it - relation manyToMany

Comment: show us your code when you make the query also please

Comment: i haven't idea how create it query, i'm bad on sql. trying to find a solution, thinking about add some weight to each interest - and then find by interests weights for users...

Comment: Interesting question! I'll think about it. @AlessandroMinoccheri I don't see why more code is necessary. IMHO this question is clear and useful without it.

Comment: easy, when you write a question you have to put your code, your try, not only ask for an advice without code. Only a little piece of you try is necessary I think. Too easy to write: "I don't know how to do a thing, can you solve me the problem?" :) I would like to know what user has tried before ask @StephanVierkant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use simple sql (not DQL) in order to extract only the id of the user that match the criteria. 
A simple query could be:

```
select distinct user_id, count(*) from users_interests
where interest_id in (1,3,5) --- your interest ids
group by 1
order by 2 DESC;
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it

1. Find user with at least 1 interest of your list (Simple Dql Query)
2. Count number of common interest in php.
   For example using `count(array_intersect($userInterestsIds, $wantedIds))`
3. You have all the wanted info, display it as you want